# Trouble in Simple app for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I have a problem. I have 2 classes "Rating" (with .h and .m), "RatingViewController" (with .h and .m).

Rating.h

```
#import 
@interface Rating : NSObject {
    int usrLyrics;
    int usrMusic;
    int usrTotal;
}
- (void) setUsrTotal;
@end
```

Rating.m

```
#import "Rating.h"
@implementation Rating
-(void) incUsrLyrics
{
    usrLyrics = 5;
}
- (void) incUsrMusic {
    usrMusic = 6;
}
- (void) setUsrTotal {
    usrTotal = usrMusic + usrLyrics;
}
}
@end
```

RatingViewController.h

```
@interface RatingItudeViewController : UIViewController {
    Rating *rating;
}
- (IBAction) submitRating;
```

RatingViewController.m

```
#import "RatingItudeViewController.h"

@implementation RatingItudeViewController

- (IBAction) submitRating {
    [rating setUsrTotal];
    NSLog(@"usrTotal is %i", [rating usrTotal]);
}
@end
```

It's looks simple, but doesn't work, in Console always "usrTotal is 0".
Help me please.

UPDATED

Just now, I add couple lines in RatingViewController.m

```
- (IBAction) submitRating {
    [rating incUsrMusic];
    [rating incUsrLyrics];
    [rating setUsrTotal];
    NSLog(@"usrTotal is %d", [rating usrTotal]);
}
```

and in Rating.h

```
-(void) incUsrLyrics;
- (void) incUsrMusic;
- (void) setUsrTotal;
- (int) usrTotal;
```

And when a press a button, in console again  "usrTotal is 0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, you need to put initialization of *usrMusic* and  *usrLyrics* variables into **init** constructor message. By default they are assigned values of 0. 0+0 is 0, hence the result.

Comment: but if i want than values changes when I press a button? what should i do?

Comment: I don't see any apparent reason why it shouldn't work. How to do you instantiate your *rating* variable?

Comment: I uploaded that project to github, can u look? maybe i'm missing something. https://github.com/itunik/Rating2

Answer (score 1):

The methods `incUsrLyrics` and `incUsrMusic` don't ever get called anywhere, thus never setting their initial values. If these values are essential to the operation of the class then they should be established in that class's initializer.

In Rating.m

```
- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        usrLyrics = 5;
        usrMusic = 6;
    }

    return self;
}
```

or better yet, a more specific initializer...

```
- (id)initWithUserLyrics:(NSInteger)lyricsValue music:(NSInteger)musicValue
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        usrLyrics = lyricsValue;
        usrMusic = musicValue;
    }

    return self;
}
```